# Finding nth power of a matrices using diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

I'm trying to find the nth power of the followin matrice.
\begin{bmatrix}2&2&0\\1&2&1\\1&2&1\end{bmatrix}
I have computed the eigen values of this matrice which are $\lambda_1=0$ $\lambda_2=1$ and $\lambda_3=4$. I have written down the diagonal matrice D:
\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&4\end{bmatrix}
Now I know the this equality holds:
$P^{-1}AP=D \implies A=PDP^{-1}$ and I can find the following relation
$A^n=PD^nP^{-1}$
I can find P bu putting eigenvalues one by one into my matrice. I have found P to be

\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\1&1&1\\-1&1&1\end{bmatrix}
and also $P^{-1}$ to be the following
\begin{bmatrix}0&\dfrac{1}{2}&-\dfrac{1}{2}\\-1&\dfrac{1}{2}&\dfrac{1}{2}\\1&0&0\end{bmatrix}

all I need to do is multiply theese 3 matrices but I keep finding a different solution than my textbook anwser key. Where am I doing a mistake? Is there something wrong with my approach.

The textbook answer is the following:
\begin{bmatrix}4+2\cdot4^n&3\cdot4^n & -4+4^n\\-2+2\cdot4^n&3\cdot4^n&2+4^n\\-2+2\cdot4^n&3\cdot4^n&2+4+n\end{bmatrix}
the matrix times $\dfrac{1}{6}$

Comment: Might help to add what the textbook solution is

Comment: There is only the anwser. I will add it now

Comment: The columns of $P$ should be the eigenvectors, no? I don't think they are?

Comment: ok I think I miscalculated something thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with your $P$ since $(1,-1,1)$ should be present as column since it is the eigenvector for $\lambda=0$, let check indeed that $A(1,-1,1)=0$.

Check again your derivation.

You should obtain that [Wolfram solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B2,2,0%7D,%7B1,2,1%7D,%7B1,2,1%7D%7D)

Comment: I did not know that wolfram can find eigenspaces and eigenvectors. Thank you. I think I miscalcalated something . Have a nice day :) (I will accept your solution as anwser in 3 mins)

Comment: @GGphys You are welcome. Note that Wolfram is very useful to solve or to check but it is also important to solve some problems fully by hand to get confident with the method and to know what kind of check to make to verify the solution when you can't use Wolfram.

Answer (score 0):

Check your eigenvalues and your eigenvectors again. I found that your matrix A does not satisfy $AV=\lambda V$ for one of your eigenvalues.